# Translate Piper Aircraft Performance Graphs to mathematical functions

Tags: exponential-function, quadratics, quadratic-programming

I'm quite stuck at that question, and I'd like to know what would be the best approach for the following task:

Piper Aircraft Corporation offers a section in their aircraft manuals which contains performance graphs on the specified aircraft. In this example, the screenshot below is a scan from the Piper Archer II manual which determines the distance it takes to lift off from ground with zero flaps.

[image: Page 5-14 from Piper Archer II AFM stating zero flaps take off performance]

However, the graphs are designed to be used in pre-flight preparations using a pencil. There's an example on every graph how to use it - on the next image, the graph is explained:

[image: Explained calculations on same graph]

You start on the bottom with a temperature, make a line straight to your airport height, and continue from there to the next graph. On the beginning of the graph, you go with the function until you reach your aircraft takeoff weight. From there on, you pass on to the next graph and follow the graph line again, until you reach the point on the X-axis which states your current wind situation. On the right Y-axis you'll find your takeoff distance in feet.

Now how do I have to approach this chart to be able to digitalize it, so I can calculate my own takeoff distance in an app, for example? Should I try to find out the function for each graph section (e.g. the quadratic function for the left graph), and then have an intermediate result to continue with the next graph - or is there a kind-of simple way to get one function for the whole graph? What would be your approach?

Thanks in advance for your inputs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer but a plan.  These kinds of charts, with intersecting families of curves, where you skootch along one curve until it crosses a particular one of the others, and you read off the answer from the name of another curve, is called a [*nomogram*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomogram).  They basically solve problems like: given $a$ and $b$ find $x$ so that $$ f(a)+g(b)= h(x),$$ and are more-or-less equivalent to slide rules with special non-linear scales (the ones nobody in class ever used, but were present in every slide rule).  They used to be at the cutting edge of computational science (in 1900, or so) and learned books were written on the subject. As an exercise, construct a nomogram for solving this problem: find $x$ given $a$ and $b$, where: $$ \log a + \log b = \log x.$$

So here is the plan: reverse engineer your charts to determine in tabular form the particular non-linear functions $f$, $g$, $h$, etc, that they embody. Then   use R or something to fit formulas to these functions of one variable.  Then you are done.  These charts were constructed from ad hoc formulas (as if they started with a plausible formula like $PV=T$ and adjusted it to read $(P+\alpha)^a (V+\beta)^c = (T+\gamma)^c$ and found the values of the fudge factors $\alpha$, $a$, etc to best fit the test flight data for their airplane. (See [this](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19930086637.pdf) for an example of this kind of rough-and ready fitting in practice.)

Here is another version of this plan.  Go to a long-established engineering library (or its internet equivalent) and look at old aeronautical engineering textbooks. The procedure for constructing these diagrams will be there.  One such explanation of what the charts mean and how to use them is [chapter 11 of *Pilot's Handbook of Aeronautical Knowlege*](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/phak/media/13_phak_ch11.pdf).  Warning: I have not read this in detail, but it looks good.

Verson 3: post this question on aviation.stackexchange

Comment: So if I understood you right, I'm going to reverse-engineer the functions air-temp, weight and wind, each by themselves. How would I start? Should I define point X on one of the curve and point Y on the same curve on another point and then set them equal - or how would you reverse-engineer such a graph? I already tried to lay a curve on them by sight using geogebra, but that can't be the way :-)

Comment: I'm not sure, and whatever you do will involve tedium.  I'd pick one of the curves on the left, say the 5000 foot one, and find the $(x,y)$ coords of 100 or so points on it, and curve fit from there.  I'd start by seeing if logarithmic transformations straighten out the curve, and I'd look at other curves in the family to give me hints.  Maybe the 7000 curve would tell me the most, because it flexes the most.  I'd also look at $f_{5000}^{-1}\circ f_{7000}$, etc. to see if (perhaps) they all take the form $f_a(t)=f_0(t)^{E(a)}$ for some $E(a)$ function.

Comment: It's too much info for me to take in, but https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/phak/media/13_phak_ch11.pdf seems to explain this kind of chart in detail pilots can understand.  Piece by piece. I'd read it before doing anything else. It's chapter 11 from an impressive-looking "Pilot's Handbook of Aeronautical Knowledge".

Comment: If anyone stumbles upon this: I achieved the desired results by digitalizing all the functions one by one. So I took the first of the three parts, digitalized the separate lines (using GeoGebra) and then get an Y axis value out of that. For values in between I calculate both and take the percentual value inbetween the results. Then I use this Y axis value to continue on the next function and so on, which gives me in the end the last Y axis value, which has to be translated into my result. For a non-mathematician, this was the easiest solution to get hold of and to get to work :)